# What's the derivative of F over R?

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative

$F(R) = \|A-RY\|^2_F$

what should $\partial F \over \partial R$ looks like?

Since $\partial \|X\|^2_F \over \partial X$ is $2X$, so $\partial \|A-RY\|_F^2$ should be $2(A-RY){ \partial RY \over \partial R}  $?

What will $\partial RY \over \partial R$ looks like?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $||U||_F^2=trace(FF^T)$, the Frobenius norm. Here $F(R)=trace((A-RY)(A-RY)^T)$.
Its derivative is $DF_R:H\rightarrow trace((-HY)(A-RY)^T+(A-RY)(-HY)^T)=trace(-2HY(A-RY)^T)=trace(-2Y(A-RY)^TH)$.

If you seek a gradient, then we consider the gradient $\nabla_R(F)$ associated to the scalar product $(U,V)=trace(U^TV)$. It is defined as follows: for every $H$, $(\nabla_R(F),H)=DF_R(H)$. Thus $\nabla_R(F)=-2(A-RY)Y^T$.

Comment: Hi, I have another qustion, if I have f(P) = 0 and f(P)=$\mu P + s\mu P^{T} S + SZ_{3}$, what is the solution? Thanks

Comment: Open a new file and give more details.